# Sending Emails from bash script in Solaris VM

Tags: bash, solaris, virtual-machine, mail-command

I am trying to send emails using the following bash script:

```
/bin/mail -s "#subject" "$emailto" < "$message"
```

It works fine on my local machine but does not work on my VM.
I looked it up and read that the issue might be related to the `/etc/hosts` file, so here is the contents of that file:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost loghost
192.168.1.200   root loghost
```

I am root user on this solaris VM.
What do I need to do change get this working?

I am getting this msg in log file

```
From MAILER-DAEMON Thu Feb 14 20:20:06 2013
Return-Path: <>
Received: from unknown (localhost [127.0.0.1])
        by unknown (8.14.4+Sun/8.14.4) with ESMTP id r1F1K57F002411
        for <root@unknown>; Thu, 14 Feb 2013 20:20:06 -0500 (EST)
Received: from localhost (localhost)
        by unknown (8.14.4+Sun/8.14.4/Submit) id r1F1K51c002398;
        Thu, 14 Feb 2013 20:20:06 -0500 (EST)
Date: Thu, 14 Feb 2013 20:20:06 -0500 (EST)
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem <MAILER-DAEMON@unknown>
Message-Id: <201302150120.r1F1K51c002398@unknown>
To: root@unknown
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
        boundary="r1F1K51c002398.1360891206/unknown"
Subject: Returned mail: see transcript for details
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated (failure)
Content-Length: 1287

This is a MIME-encapsulated message

--r1F1K51c002398.1360891206/unknown
```

Comment: Could you expand on 'not working?'  What isn't working?  Is there anything in your mail logs?

Comment: I am not getting email to.did not check the error logs

Comment: always check logs first; they'll tell you faster than stack exchange :)

Comment: You need to properly configure Sendmail. Let me guess, you didn't configure it?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, you should configure sendmail. 
Most likely the only thing you need will be editing the sendmail.conf and setting the DS"IP" for the relay host.

Also make sure that your main mail server accepts mail from your VM.